# LINQ-to-SQL classes from a select statement

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am a little new to linq-to-sql. I was just thinking suppose you wanted a subset of fields (in your db table) to actually be a data model in your application, what do you do? What I have thought of so far is to create a view from the actual db table and build linq-able classes using it.

Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

try these [Walkthrough: Creating LINQ to SQL Classes (O/R Designer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384428.aspx)

or these implemented in MVC [Creating Model Classes with LINQ to SQL](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-model-classes-with-linq-to-sql-cs)

Answer (score 0):

One option is you can create **[Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)** and use it.